# Consolidate/discard events in count window

Tags: apache-flink

I just started using Flink and have a problem I'm not sure how to solve. I get events from a Kafka Topic, these events represent a "beacon" signal from a mobile device. The device sends an event every 10 seconds.

I have an external customer that is asking for a beacon from our devices but every 60 seconds. Since we are already using Flink to process other events I thought I could solve this using a count window, but I'm struggling to understand how to "discard" the first 5 events and emit only the last one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to do this. As Far as I understand the idea is as follows: You receive beacon signal each 10 sec but You actually only need the most actual one and disard the others since the client asks for the data each 60 sec.

The simplest would be ofc to use `ProcessFunction` with count/event time window as You said. The type of the window actually depends on Your requirements. Then You sould do something like this:

```
stream.timeWindow([windowSize]).process(new CustomWindowProcessFunction())
```

The signature of the `process()` method of the `ProcessWindowFunction`is as follows, depending on the type of the actual function `def process(context: Context, elements: Iterable[IN], out: Collector[OUT])`. So basically it gives you the acces to all window elements, so You can easily only push further the elements You like.

While this is the simplest idea, you may want also to take a look at the Flink timers, as they seem to be a good solution for Your issue. They are described [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html#timers).